How to change the Firebase region when using Firebase Functions?
I encountered an error when trying to deploy my TypeScript function to Firebase. The error message I received is:
Error: A function in region us-central1 cannot listen to a bucket in region eu
I tried to find any settings for this in Firebase Functions and other places in the Firebase console. I also attempted to deploy the function with its own configuration like this:
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp({
    projectId: '<myAppId>'
  }, 'europe-west1');

// HTTP function for helloWorld (for testing)
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase with TypeScript!");
});

But it doesn't help

You need to set the region in the function builder configuration, not the admin SDK. There are lots of examples on how to do this on Stack Overflow and in the API documentation.  It seems you're using old v1 type functions, so be sure you're looking at something for the v1 API and not v2.  The builder will go like this: functions.region(...).https.onRequest(...). There is also plenty to be found using a web search for the title of your question.
